# Using bluetooth for authentication

Tags: authentication, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to use bluetooth for authenticating a user (bluetooth device).

My first idea was to use iBeacon which would be weared by a user. If that user would approach authenticating device (central), that device would use MAC/UUID/Major/Minor of iBeacon to identify the user. Unfortunately it is possible to clone iBeacon and so more advanced approach is required.

Does BLE has some mechanism for that? One option would be that central device would connect to peripherial one and use some PKI to authenticate it.

Or maybe there is something for this purpose already in BLE protocol.

Is these some well known solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The [FIDO2](https://fidoalliance.org/fido2/) standard includes a variant where a Bluetooth device acts as a secure key. [Google's Titan Security Key](https://cloud.google.com/titan-security-key/) is such an implementation (or rather of the older U2F specification).

The Bluetooth specific part is found in the [CTAP2](https://fidoalliance.org/specs/fido-v2.0-ps-20190130/fido-client-to-authenticator-protocol-v2.0-ps-20190130.html) specification. But it is quite some work to implement it and there is no reference code for Bluetooth.

The overall protocol with a private and a public key and a challenge/attestation procedure will still apply for a simpler implementation.

BTW: FIDO2 is not very wide spread yet but many companies are working hard to implement it. I think it will prevail - but mostly without external security keys such as USB dongles and Bluetooth device. It will be successful with fingerprint readers and face recognition technologies built into all future devices, be it smart phones or laptops.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am looking for something simple I could implement on ESP32 or NRF5x device.

Comment: I almost suspected so. Using a private/public key pair is still a good and doable option. The service that requires authentication creates a challenge (mainly using random data), the device signs or encrypts it with the private key and the service verifies the response with the public key.